# Checking if a nested dictionary key exists in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, data-structures, dictionary

I am trying to use a dictionary of dictionaries in Excel VBA. What I'm trying to find out is whether the nested dictionary has a key already, and if not, add it.

My data looks like the following:

```
Country, Customer, Purchased
US, Alan, Lawnmower
US, Alan, Hammer
US, Karen, Donkey
US, Simon, Mustang
MX, Carl, Lawnmower
MX, Alan, Donkey
...
```

The data structure I have in mind looks like `dictionary --> dictionary --> array` -- that is, `country --> customer --> purchased`.

The code I am using to find out if a country does not exist in the `country` dictionary is:

```
If Not dataset.Exists(country) Then 
...
```

However, code that looks like the following does not work:

```
If Not dataset.Exists(country)(customer) Then 
....
```

How do you check the next level of dictionary entries? Is it a case of storing the contents of the country dictionary in an array, then checking that (which seems a mess)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this one:

```
If Not dataset.Exists(country) Then
    'if country doesn't exists do sth
ElseIf Not dataset(country).Exists(customer) Then
    'if country exists, but customer doesn't exists do sth
End If
```

Comment: Does that also means that you can keep the dot notation running for all the dictionaries you may have nested?

Comment: Sure, *in you case* (when you are using nested dictionary as item) `dataset(country)` returns ditionary object (if item with key `country` exists), so you could use any operations supported by dictionary object with `dataset(country)`: `.Add`, `.Exists` and so on. For two times nested dictionary approach would be the same